# Перенос строки при длинном выводе

Tags: php

Как сделать на php при выводе информации, чтобы был перенос строки, если больше 300 символов? P.S. свойство в css max-width не работает.

Comment: @Руслан Невечеря, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Хотите на PHP? Будет вам :)

```
$superString = implode("\n", str_split($superString, 300));
echo nl2br($superString); // <br /> в месте переноса
```

Или вот так:

```
$superString = implode("<br />", str_split($superString, 300));
```

Comment: Значит вы его неправильно приготовили :) В HTML'е использовали? Переносы другие поставить надо. См. дополнение к ответу.

Comment: А мне казалось, что комментарий был немного другим.. 

В любом случае, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: В чём конкретно заключается различие между вторым и первым случаем?

Answer (score 4):

А еще в php есть функция [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php), которая сильно помогает.

Answer (score 3):

Я тоже сталкивался с такой проблемой на практике, и, скажу, что всякие там word-wrap`ы здесь не помогут( во-первых, это свойство не кроссбраузерно ). Здесь придется писать собственный сплиттер, который будет вставлять перенос строки тогда, если на протяжении, скажем, последних 60 символов не было замечено ни одного пробела или переноса строки.
Так как я с этой задачей уже сталкивался, то писал сплиттер. Вот и он:

```
function splitter($str,$col,$pos=0)
{
    $arr = array();
    $found = false;
    for($i=$pos;$i<mb_strlen($str);$i++)
    {
    if($str[$i]==" " || $str[$i]=="\n" || $str[$i]=="\r")  $found=true;

        if($i!=0)
        if($i%$col==0)
        {
            if($found==false)
            {
                array_push($arr,$i);
            }
            $found = false; 
            }

        }
    for($i = 0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
    {
        $s1=mb_substr($str,0,$arr[$i]);
    $s2=mb_substr($str,$arr[$i],mb_strlen($str)-$arr[$i]+1);
        $str = $s1."<br>".$s2;
        }
    return $str;
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста =)

Answer (score 0):

[word-wrap](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap).

Comment: См. теги внимательней, ему нужно решение на php

Comment: P.S. свойство в css max-width не работает.
Если автор делал такое, то может ему и так подойдет

Comment: На самом деле, это просто ирония. Просто достаточно часто лепят тег `php` куда ни попадя